# how to compare strings in using CDBCRITERIA in Yii?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii, criteria

I am using Yii framework, I want to do some search filtering, but I am getting wrong results in some cases as follow:

I have 2 check-boxes: Canada and united states, if I check Canada I will get all the results related to Canada only, while if I check united states I will get all the results in the db regardless its related to united states or not, and this bug is absolutely happen because united states string is of 2 parts so it need to be in quotations. here is my code:

the view page:

```
 echo '<div class="checkbox"><label>'.
       CHtml::checkBox($m2->tag, false, array('value'=>"$m2->tag")).$m2->tag              
       .'</label></div>';
```

the controller:

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
        $c->order = "idJob DESC";
            $model = Jobs::model()->findAll($c);
            $model2 = Tags::model()->findAll();
            $lcr = "";
            $tag="";
            foreach($model2 as $m2){

                if(isset($_POST[$m2->tag])){

                    $tag = $_POST[$m2->tag];                           

                    if($m2->category=='Location')

                        $lcr[]= $tag; 
                }
            }


            if($lcr!="")

                $c->addInCondition('location', $lcr, 'AND');

            $model = Jobs::model()->findAll($c);
```

Comment: I don't see any SQL here. What does this have to do with SQL? This looks like something Yii specific using their model system.

Comment: the `criteria->addInCondition()` generates an sql query as `attribute In (1, 2, 3)...`

Comment: That's Yii or the ORM Yii uses, not SQL.

Comment: @mawburn ok thanks, but I didn't find a suitable title :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it sounds like I found a solution for this problem and its working correctly, here is the solution:

in the controller:

```
 foreach($model2 as $m2){

            if (strpos($m2->tag, ' ') !== FALSE)
                $m2->tag = str_replace(" ","_",$m2->tag);

                if(isset($_POST["$m2->tag"])){
....
```

So, as you see in the code, if the `tag` contain any white space it will be replaced by `_` , and in the HTML the id attribute will replace the white space by `_` automatically, so they are matched now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code on your code its will work you

```
$criteria->addSearchCondition('location', 'YOUR SEARCH STRING', false);
```